# Android -- Storing data on shared preferences

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, password-encryption, storing-data

I'm currently designing an application which has initial login page. I provide remember me functionality and I stored username and password values in shared preferences. I illustrated my sample code below.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyAppSettings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("username",username);
edit.putString("password",password); 
edit.commit();
```

**Info:** *Suppose username and password are string variables which are filled by user*

Whenever user sets checkbox remember me, I store these variables in shared preferences.

I wonder that is this way safe and reliable for performing this kind of operation?

I mean that can these variables be reachable from outside the application?

Also, do I have to encrypt password of the user and store in shared preferences?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean that can these variables be reachable from outside the application?

Anyone with a rooted device can view your SharedPreferences. It is simply an XML file stored on the device.

> Also, do I have to encrypt password of the user and store in shared preferences?

It would be safer to do so, yes. Also encrypt the username while you're about it.

Comment: If I understood well , to do the encryption/decryption you need a key... How do you store this key securely ?? And if you don't store the key, what's the point of asking the user a password to decrypt his stored password ?

Answer (score 4):

Although Raghav Sood did answer your question correctly, your approach to the app design is fundamentally wrong in my opinion.

Modern day practices dictate that you should not store username and password at all in your app. Instead the login process should generate an oauth token that your app can then encrypt and remember for future access the web-server.

To have a general reading about oauth tokens you can check the wikipedia article on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth and just as example, twitter uses that approach for apps connected to it https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Comment: How would you estimate my authentication methodology from my question?

Comment: I'm sure I already answered that but I'll repeat: Your question directly says that you're storing username and password on the device and asks about safe and reliable. Storing username and password on the device is neither safe or reliable.

Comment: Sometimes you have to send credentials to log in a website you don't own... You have no way to choose the authentication scheme.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the user submit the username & password
2. Once the backend validates the user, make the server return a [JWT](https://jwt.io/)
3. Store this JWT in shared preferences securely using [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)
4. Use this JWT to authenticate user in the future